# Getting call options such as skype/viber again

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-2

My question is similar to this :

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/473947-calling-dialer-viber-skype.html

But not quite the same. I've chosen phone as my default calling options, and I'm ok with that. Now my question is that, what do I press when I want to call a contact via Viber/Skype/Other app again? What do I press to get asked again?

Without resetting the default calling option, is there a such option ?

Comment: You want readers to go to some other site to get the details of your question? Stack Exchange's purpose is to create a set of questions and answer that are useful for more people than the original asker. At the very least, if that link stops working, this question becomes absolutely useless.

Comment: How do you expect to be able to choose another app when you don't want to open a dialog to choose another app? You'll have to call from the app itself (e.g. Skype) then.

Comment: I thought there might be some trick like clicking on the image of the contact and you get prompted for gmail, message, viber etc. but not skype

Answer (score 1):

The option to choose what application to use when making a call (or anything else, such as open a webpage) happens when you don't have a default set. So if you want to get asked whether to use Dialler/Skype/Viber when you try to call a contact, then you need to clear the default settings for Dialler. You won't get the prompt otherwise.

There is no way to set this up on a per-number or per-contact basis in the Dialler.

Comment: well I know of the option to clear the default choice, but here is the deal I'm happy to have Phone as my default choice but I still want to be able to call via skype or viber contacts from my phone book. Now I've got phone set as default for all of them. But I still don't want to choose the contact type every time, want to choose when I want to and at the same time have the phone as default choice

Comment: Dialing from the app itself is the only option then.

Comment: Don't think of it as "Phone is the default action for *this* contact" think of it as "Phone is the default action for *calling*". You can either bind Phone to calling, or you can leave calling as default action free, but it works for all contacts, not just one.

Answer (score -1):

Go to setting, manage applications, press the ALL tab and scroll down to Dialler/Skype/Viber go to options then select CLEAR DEFAULT button.

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/590961-dialer-default-search-settings.html

Comment: The question clearly states "Without resetting the default calling option[...]".